# Use list comprehension to extract value from another dataframe based on a key from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe test which has a column `company`.
I have another dataframe bsr which has 2 columns, `market` and `region`, both contain the same data type.

I want to extract the region of each company.

For that I wrote the following code:

```py
test['region'] = [for company in test['company']]
```

I am not able to get the correct syntax of how to look for that company in the market column of bsr dataframe as key and get it's region as value.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/4046632)

Answer (score 0):

Simple merge should add region to test DataFrame. In case when you don't have all markets in bsr and you don't want to loose these data from test, use parameter `how='left'` in merge.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'company': ['A', 'B']})
bsr = pd.DataFrame({'market': ['A', 'B'], 'region': [1, 2]})
test_with_region = test.merge(bsr, left_on='company', right_on='market')
```

Also you can then get rid of market column from `test_with_region`